# What is the best way to retain and download locally a .txt file that is generated during an Azure Devops release?

Tags: azure, powershell, file, azure-devops

I am generating a `.txt` file which includes information about the deployment during my release at a specific stage located at the `$(System.BuildDirectory)`. How can I obtain this `.txt` file and download it locally, for example onto my desktop?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I need to check on the next run, then I will mark as accepted if it works! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can try to add a [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) task to copy the .txt file to your local machine.

[image]